# What is $1^\omega$?

Tags: exponentiation, infinity, ordinals

In Wolfram Mathworld, Ordinal exponentiation $\alpha^\beta$ is defined for limit ordinal $\beta$ as:

> If $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then if $\alpha=0$, $\alpha^\beta=0$. If  $\alpha\neq 0$ then, $\alpha^\beta$ is the least ordinal greater than any ordinal in the set $\{\alpha^\gamma:\gamma<\beta\}.$

That lead me to think, what is $1^\omega$?

According to the definition above,
$$1^\omega=\max\{1^\gamma:\gamma<\omega\}+1=\max\{1^\gamma:\gamma\in\mathbb N\}+1=\max\{1\}+1=1+1=2$$
Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: The definition from Wolfram is flawed, it's correct for $\alpha > 1$ but not for $1$. In fact, $1^{\omega}=1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation.

Comment: PS But yes, your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, but Mathworld's definition is wrong: it should specify the least ordinal greater than **or equal to** all the ordinals in the set $\{ \alpha^\gamma : \gamma < \beta \}$, with the result that $1^\omega = 1$. More generally, $1^\alpha = 1$ for any ordinal $\alpha$.